# jankFrameListener run 2 times for onCreate

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing, metrics

```
FrameData(frameStartNanos=8841146369258, frameDurationUiNanos=69020289, frameDurationCpuNanos=74082747, isJank=true, states=[prabhat_Activity: MainActivity])

ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Displayed com.example.myapplication/.ui.MainActivity: +127ms

FrameData(frameStartNanos=8841221785642, frameDurationUiNanos=7009654, frameDurationCpuNanos=9558113, isJank=false, states=[prabhat_Activity: MainActivity])
```

**in the above sequence, frame rate logs callback run 2 times for activity onCreate . how this is possible ?**

Basically , I got a point why it running 2 times but not a way to differentiate from which screen it's called,

So, I have an activity and fragment on top of it. I add putState in onCreate of activity so, it send event 2 times i.e 1 for activity and 1 for fragment but I didn't add putState in fragment.
How I can differentiate ?

**Activity**

```
val metricsStateHolder = PerformanceMetricsState.getHolderForHierarchy(binding.root)
jankStats = JankStats.createAndTrack(window, jankFrameListener)
metricsStateHolder.state?.putState("prabhat_Activity", javaClass.simpleName)
```

**Fragment**

Removed all code related to junk state bt still got it 2 time, bt when i remove adding fragment on top of activity then it only calls 1 times.